# ff9 in Wireshark Capture

Tags: wireshark

I am attempting to save a wireshark capture for later analysis and replay and I noticed that the reconstituted stream has a series off ff9/n scattered through it which is breaking up the message.  What is causing this sequence to be embedded in the stream?  I do not see this artifact in other requests so is this just a reflection of what is actually on the wire or just a idiosyncrasy with wireshark?

Ex.

```
POST /gatewayvnext/xdr.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:b08aed3e-8972-4f75-a5f1-74ee6f0f9a4e"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"; action="urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b"
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.2.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: directuat
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

ff9

--uuid:b08aed3e-8972-4f75-a5f1-74ee6f0f9a4e
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml"; action="urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reflection of what's actually on the wire.

Note that the HTTP headers include "Transfer-Encoding: chunked".  Those items are part of [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).